# Split array values in javascript+codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, codeigniter

[image: i have attached the screenshot of my output. Now its an array format, i want to split those array values from javascript.]

View File:

```
<form name="sortdata" method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url;?>home/sortby">
<select id="sortMyData" name="sortMyData" class="sortMydata">
    <option value="lowhigh">Low to high price</option>
    <option value="highlow">High to low price</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" id="baseurl" name="baseurl" value="<?php echo base_url;?>">
</form>

<div id="sortbyprice" class="span6">


</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".sortMydata").change(function()
{
var baseurl=$("#baseurl").val();
var sortMyData=$("#sortMyData").val();
//alert(baseurl);
alert(sortMyData);
$.ajax
({
type:"GET",
url:baseurl + 'product/sortbydetails/' + sortMyData,
//data:this.value,
cache: false,
success:function(html)
    { 
        var length=html.length;
        alert(html);
        alert(html[0]); 

    }
});
});
});
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public function sortbydetails()
    {
        $lowhigh=$this->uri->segment(3);
        if($lowhigh=="lowhigh")
        {
            $lowtohighprice=$this->product_model->getlowtohighprice();  
            $count=count($lowtohighprice);
            //echo $count;

            for ($i=0; $i < $count ; $i++) 
                { 

                    foreach ($lowtohighprice as $key => $value) {
                    $sortby[] = array_values($value);

                }
                    print_r($sortby);
            }
            //print_r($lowtohighprice);
        }
        else
        {
            $hightolowprice=$this->product_model->gethightolowprice();
            //print_r($hightolowprice);
        }

    }
```

I am trying to split the array values from javascript. I wrote an jquery ajax code and display the output in a div. Now am getting the output as an array values, i want to split that array values. I spend a whole day to achieve this task, but i couldnt able to resolve.

Comment: we use split function to make an array from a string which has repetition of a character.what you exactly asking for?

Comment: You should use `console.log()` rather than `alert()`. It's much easier to work with, and the output will arrive in the JavaScript console you already have showing up on your screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not get what you want exactly.
You can use any loop to get all values from array.

```
var myarray = [1,2,3,4];
for(var i= 0; i< myarray.length; i++)
{
alert(myarray[i]);
}
```

**EDIT:**

For 2 dimensional arrays

```
var myarray = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]];
for(var i= 0; i< myarray.length; i++)
  for(var j=0; j < myarray[i].length; j++)
     {
      alert(myarray[i][j]);
     }
```

Comment: i have attached the screenshot of my output. Now its an array format, i want to split those array values from javascript.

Answer (score 0):

IN ES6

you can use map

var myarray = [1,2,3,4];

myarray.map(a=>alert(a));

it also return values